# In-App purchase issue in iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in-App purchase in one of app.
everything is working on iOS 7 and iOS 8.
But when i am trying to purchase on **iOS 8 Simulators** and **iPad Air 8.0**.
it's giving me below error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x7ab1cb70 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Comment: making sure you are using the test user account, and then the in app purchases name are correct on both sides.

Comment: Yes i am using test credentials and i am successfully using them on iPhone device.

Comment: I have the same issue. Test purchases work fine on devices, but not on Simulator . And apple review rejected my apps because in app purchase doesn't work on iPad Air and iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1. Have you found solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW1

StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Comment: But what about iPad Air?

Comment: For iPad air the problem should be related on the settings. Take a  look at the documentation http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1368

Comment: Those are Xcode 5 release notes. We're on Xcode 6 now. Many StoreKit calls do work in the simulator now with Xcode 6 & iOS 8, but not all.

Comment: please uncheck this as an correct answer. Storekit does work on XCode 6 & iOS 8 Simulator